# ctx.query is null in jOOQ DefaultExecutionListener resultEnd

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a custom implementation of `DefaultExecutionListener`. I use it to log queries, and their results.

I overwrote `resultEnd`, and it does work for most queries. I have an update query for which no query can be logged, because `ctx.query` is null.

I put a breakpoint on `resultStart`, and there the query is still set. Why is it lost, and how can I retrieve it again in `resultEnd`?

Please see comments for a link to a test project showing the behaviour.

Comment: It's query unlikely that `ctx.query()` suddenly becomes `null` given that in `DefaultExecuteContext` (the only implementation of `ExecuteContext`), the `Query` reference is `final`. Can you perhaps create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just found a hint: `Note that this method is not called when executing queries that do not return a result, or when executing routines.` in the JavaDoc of resultEnd, which confuses me, since it seems to be called in this case.

Comment: I've debugged the code some more. The `resultEnd` function is called because of a `fetch` on a new CurserImpl` on line 827 in `AbstractDMLQuery`, with a differnt `ctx2`. The `ctx2` does not have the query. The `ctx` which was used for the `executeStart` and `executeEnd` on line 725 does have the query.

Comment: Here is a test project showing the problem: https://github.com/ayedo/jooq-loggin-problem

Comment: I see now, thanks for the help in reproducing this. I can confirm, this is a bug: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8025. I don't know what to do with your question, though. The thing about `ctx.query` being null doesn't really seem to be related...

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! My goal is to log every query, and its result in a single log statement, for queries which do not have a result, I would like to log something like "No Result". Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, remember if there is a result, and then print that information on the `end()` event.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advise, but I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by 'remember'? Store in a field? Wouldn't concurrency be a problem, matching of which query created which result?

Comment: Of course you would store it in a field. You're in full control of your own `ExecuteListener` instance. You can avoid any concurrency problem. This is the beauty of an SPI. It allows you to do whatever you want, if you get it right.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll try to get it right then ;)

Comment: I'll be happy to answer any specific questions you may have here on SO :)